# Facing issue while binding data to laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have some data that i am binding to laravel view but it is giving me error specially for the integer values even if key exist in data,

I have use var_dump to check data types.

```
object(stdClass) #586 (29) { ["XCHNG"]= > string(3)
"BSE" ["Upd_Time"] => string(19)
"2019-11-01 00:00:00" ["Open_Price"] => string(4)
"2270" ["High_Price"] => string(6)
"2274.2" ["Low_Price"] => string(6)
"2195.5" ["price"] => string(7)
"2202.05" ["bbuy_qty"] => string(2)
"37" ["bbuy_price"] => string(7)
"2202.05" ["bsell_qty"] => string(2)
"35" ["bsell_price"] => string(7)
"2202.05" ["Value"] => string(9)
"2431.3468" ["OldPrice"] => string(6)
"2270.2" ["Pricediff"] => string(18)
"-68.14999999999964" ["change"] => string(18)
"-3.001938155228598" ["Trd_Qty"] => string(6)
"109603" ["Volume"] => string(6)
"109603" ["HI_52_WK"] => string(4)
"2296" ["LO_52_WK"] => string(4)
"1787" ["H52DATE"] => string(19)
"2019-09-03 00:00:00" ["L52DATE"] => string(19)
"2018-11-26 00:00:00" ["Trd_Value"] => string(9)
"243134680" ["co_name"] => string(3)
"TCS" ["sc_group"] => string(1)
"A" ["CompLname"] => string(29)
"Tata Consultancy Services Ltd" ["Sc_code"] => string(6)
"532540" ["ListInfo"] => string(6)
"listed" ["B52HighAdj"] => string(4)
"2296" ["b52LowAdj"] => string(4)
"1787" ["isin"] => string(12)
"INE467B01029"
}
```

**Controller** Code :

```
if (!empty($cocode)) {
    foreach ($cocode as $cocode_data) {
        $param2 = array($cocode_data->Co_Code, $cocode_data->Exchange);
        $stock_live = $PortfolioModel->get_stock_live_details($param2);
        foreach ($stock_live as $res) {
            array_push($stock_live_details, $res);
        }
    }
}
```

**View** Code :

```
@foreach($stock_live_details as $stock_live)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$stock_live->co_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$stock_live->XCHNG}}</td>
        <td>{{$stock_live->Open_Price}}</td>
        <td>{{$stock_live->change}}</td>
        <td>{{$stock_live->Low_Price}}</td>
        <td>{{$stock_live->HI_52_WK}}</td>
        <td>{{$stock_live->LO_52_WK}}</td>
        <td>{{$stock_live->Low_Price}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

It is giving **error** as
            (2/2) ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$Open_Price
            even if key exist in data
[image]

Comment: it apparently does not exist on some instance

Comment: Controller code please!

Comment: pleaseput proper controller code.

Comment: Where does the data come from?  The property looks like it should be there based on the `var_dump`.  But it's possible that the encoding from the data source contains extra characters in the name that can't be seen, making your property seem inaccessible.  If so, you will need to strip these characters as you define the properties.

Comment: (2/2) ErrorException ... Can you please share your (1/2) error?